# Atalho/Autocomplete no SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Estou usando o *SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)* na versão 17.5 de 2017 e gostaria de criar alguns atalhos/autocomplete para tornar o processo de busca um pouquinho mais rápida, sem implantar isso em alguma aplicação, mais para questão do uso do SSMS.

Seria algo como digitar: `@slc` e auto completar para `select * from` ou simplismente um `@join` e auto completar para `select * from tbl1 t1 inner join tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id`

Existe alguma forma de criar uma atalho ou autocomplete para este caso? Como?

Answer (score -1):

Você consegue criar um template XML com o código que você quer automatizar, e importar o snippet através do menu "Ferramentas" - "Gerenciador de trechos de códigos..."

Aqui tem um exemplo de template, a consulta vai dentro do CDATA[] disponível no nó "Snippet":

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
<_locDefinition xmlns="urn:locstudio">  
    <_locDefault _loc="locNone" />  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Title</_locTag>  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Description</_locTag>  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">Author</_locTag>  
    <_locTag _loc="locData">ToolTip</_locTag>  
   <_locTag _loc="locData">Default</_locTag>  
</_locDefinition>  
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
<Header>  
<Title>TryCatch</Title>  
<Shortcut></Shortcut>  
<Description>Example Snippet for Try-Catch.</Description>  
<Author>SQL Server Books Online Example</Author>  
<SnippetTypes>  
<SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>  
</SnippetTypes>  
</Header>  
<Snippet>  
<Declarations>  
 <Literal>  
  <ID>CatchCode</ID>  
        <ToolTip>Code to handle the caught error</ToolTip>  
        <Default>CatchCode</Default>  
    </Literal>  
</Declarations>  
<Code Language="SQL"><![CDATA[  
SELECT @@VERSION,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as ProductVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') as Edition,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') as SPStatus
]]>  
</Code>  
</Snippet>  
</CodeSnippet>  
</CodeSnippets>
```

Apesar de existir um nó chamado "shortcut", parece que esta funcionalidade não foi implementada, eu vi várias perguntas no ST onde se comenta isso.

Existem ferramentas que permitem automatizar este processo, algumas são gratuitas, como esta:

https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-complete.aspx

Caso você precise de mais informações, estes links explicam com detalhes como ativar o intellisense e trabalhar com snippets:

https://codingsight.com/sql-server-intellisense-and-autocomplete/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/add-transact-sql-snippets?view=sql-server-2017

https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-manage-t-sql-code-snippets/